# An integral that has a singularity

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, improper-integrals, measurable-functions

Question: Does the following integral hold for almost all $x$, where $f$ is a positive measurable function: $$\int_\mathbb{R} \frac{f(t)}{(x - t)^2} dt = +\infty$$

Comment: Yes, it's divergent, but [some meaning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_regularization) could still be attributed to it...

Comment: Thank you. But I'm unable to produce a proof for this unless f is nice, say, being continuous, etc.

Comment: see also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30703/a-set-with-a-finite-integral-of-measure-zero

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that if the integral is finite for even a single $x$, then $f$ is locally integrable on $\mathbb{R}$.  Suppose that this is the case.  If $x$ is a Lebesgue point of $f$, then $$\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\frac{1}{2\varepsilon}\int_{x-\varepsilon}^{x+\varepsilon}f(t)dt=f(x).$$  Since $\frac{1}{(x-t)^2}>\frac{1}{\varepsilon^2}$ on the interval $(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)$, this implies that $$\frac{1}{2\varepsilon}\int_{x-\varepsilon}^{x+\varepsilon}\frac{f(t)}{(x-t)^2}dt\gt \frac{f(x)}{2\varepsilon^2}$$ for sufficiently small $\varepsilon>0$, which in turn implies that $$\int_{\mathbb R}\frac{f(t)}{(x-t)^2}dt>\frac{f(x)}{\varepsilon}$$ for sufficiently small, and hence all, $\varepsilon>0$.  Thus the integral is infinite for such $x$, and so the integral is infinite almost everywhere by the Lebesgue differentiation theorem.